# Auto populate rows according to another cell content

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I want to make an excel sheet to design a steel bunker. I have added all the formulas and it works. But according to dimension and shape of bunker we need to add some horizontal stiffeners to the bunker body. This process need iteration. If the initial locations of the stiffeners are not good enough, you have to change the location of the all stiffeners maybe not only location but number.

To size stiffeners, I have to calculate the pressure, tensile forces and moment at the level of those stiffeners. This calculation formula is a function of depth "z" like below:

`f(z)=((γ*Ra)÷μ)*(1-e(-μ*K*z)÷Ra)`

If we set the top of the bunker z=0 then it increases when you go down. I need f(z) where there is a stiffener. If there is 3 stiffener, I need f(z1), f(z2), and f(z3). If there is 5 stiffener then I need f(z1), f(z2), ... f(z5)

How to populate this `f(z)` values according to formula with the manually given z values.

[image]

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to calculate derivation of f(z)/dz and then find potential maximum where df(z) = 0 and then solve it and get the z?

Comment: so the df(z) = y * (u*K)*e(-u*K*z), df(z) = 0 when y, u, or K is 0. It has a limit of zero in minus infinity

Comment: @Richard I think there is a misunderstanding. I have added an image to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to handle this. It's hard to tell from the picture.

1. The simplest would be to use a UDF and do all your iterations inside the UDF. If your function does not have a single output but instead multiple outputs, you can use a UDF to return an Array instead of a single value.
2. Another way would be to set up your calculations as a single column for each Iteration, and progress by incrementally increasing the number of stiffeners.
3. If laying out your data as a column is not feasible, you can always use circular references. You need a cell where you can reset all cells to a default value if "1" is inputed, and progressively increase the number of stiffeners.

All of the above requires that the revised location of stiffeners is standard at each iteration (either a pre-determined constant or a calculated value), so that your function can go through Iteration after Iteration without user input.